# Design : Refer different properties for a object at run time

Tags: java, json

I'm looking for some advice to come up with a design for a use case on which I'm working. As a REST request I receive a Json payload something like below

```json
{ 
  "marketEvent" :{
        "category": "Finance"
        "version": 1.0       
   }
   "history" : {
     "type" : "FX"
     "value": 45.33  
     "role" : " Broker"  
   } 
}
```

For different categories (in this example Finance), I need to access different values from the JSON. In case of Finance, I need to access `history.type`, but in another category I might need to access another value.

I'm looking for a generic design in Java/Spring where I can configure different categories and what values I need to access and take action on that.

Answer (score 0):

[Jayway](https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath) is perfect for this. Along with a map from the categories and paths to the data.

Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Code

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;

public class App5 {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonDataSourceString = "{ \r\n" + 
                "  \"marketEvent\" :{\r\n" + 
                "        \"category\": \"Finance\", \r\n" + 
                "        \"version\": 1.0       \r\n" + 
                "   }, \r\n" + 
                "   \"history\" : {\r\n" + 
                "     \"type\" : \"FX\", \r\n" + 
                "     \"value\": 45.33,  \r\n" + 
                "     \"role\" : \" Broker\"  \r\n" + 
                "   } \r\n" + 
                "}";

        System.out.println(jsonDataSourceString);

        Map<String, String> categoryToJsonPath = new HashMap<>();
        categoryToJsonPath.put("Finance", "$.history.type");
        
        String pathToCategory = "$.marketEvent.category";
        
        DocumentContext jsonContext = JsonPath.parse(jsonDataSourceString);
        String categoryName = jsonContext.read(pathToCategory);
        
        System.out.println(categoryName);

        String pathToCategoryDependentField = categoryToJsonPath.get(categoryName);
        
        String categoryDependentFieldValue = jsonContext.read(pathToCategoryDependentField);

        System.out.println(categoryDependentFieldValue);
        

    }

}
```

Output:

```
{ 
  "marketEvent" :{
        "category": "Finance", 
        "version": 1.0       
   }, 
   "history" : {
     "type" : "FX", 
     "value": 45.33,  
     "role" : " Broker"  
   } 
}
Finance
FX
```

Answer (score 0):

You many try library *Josson*. Function `caseValue()` can do the job.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"marketEvent\" :{" +
    "        \"category\": \"Finance\"," +
    "        \"version\": 1.0" +
    "   }," +
    "   \"history\" : {" +
    "     \"type\" : \"FX\"," +
    "     \"value\": 45.33," +
    "     \"role\" : \" Broker\"" +
    "   }" +
    "}");
String categoryValue = josson.getString(
    "marketEvent.category.caseValue(" +
    "  'Finance', $.history.type," +
    "  'IT', $.history.type2)");
System.out.println(categoryValue);
// Output: FX
```